# Notepad++, Atom, encoding seems to be broken

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, notepad++, atom-editor

I have to edit php (`.inc`) file which was created a long ago and I don't know which editor was used to create it. The Cyrillic letters in Notepad++ are shown like they were in wrong encoding:

[image: Screenshot of Notepad++ with Cyrillic Characters]

In GitHub's Atom editor, Cyrillic letters are totally lost and replaced with the `�` character:

[image: Screenshot of Atom Editor with characters incorrectly replaced]

But in browser everything is displayed correctly! The same is true when using Windows Notepad.  Why it is displayed incorrectly in code editors and is there a way to make it look normal?

P.S. OK the thought that I just can copy it from windows notepad and save in notepad++ only now came to me :D But still curious why this happened to code editors.

**P.S.2 Problem is solved. Editors just didn't recognize the original encoding properly. When I changed it manually to Windows1251, everything became ok.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom's support for encoding isn't as mature as some other editors out there, as you have already discovered you can change the encoding in the bottom right hand corner and Atom will remember it, however there are some packages which help further:

1. Out of the box as you have discovered [Encoding Selector](https://atom.io/packages/encoding-selector) which allows you to choose how Atom interprets the contents of the text file.
2. There is a package that automatically select encoding for you named [Auto Encoding](https://atom.io/packages/auto-encoding), however it does have some issues with [certain types of file](https://github.com/t-ishii/auto-encoding/issues/12), you might find this isn't a problem.
3. Finally, there is my personal favorite, [editor-settings](https://atom.io/packages/editor-settings), which allows you to set the encoding of all files of a specific language, with a specific file extension or or directory.

As an example if you wanted to configure all `.inc` files in a directory to use `windows-1251` create a `.editor-settings` in the directory you are using and paste in the following:

```
encoding: utf-8
extensionConfig:
  inc:
    encoding: windows-1251
```